# Yii, custom WebUser property

Tags: php, authentication, yii

AFAIK I do right

UserIdentity

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    const ERROR_NOT_ACTIVE = 111;
    //
    private $role;
    private $_id;

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $oUser = User::model()->find('LOWER(login) = ?', array(strtolower($this->username)));

        if ($oUser === null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else {
            // wrong password
            if (!$oUser->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            } // user not activated by admin
            elseif ($oUser->active) {
                $this->_id = $oUser->id;
                $this->role = $oUser->role;
                $this->username = $oUser->login;
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
            } // user valid and activated
            else {
                $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NOT_ACTIVE;
            }
        }

        return $this->errorCode == self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

WebUser

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        var_dump($this->getState('role'));
        return ($this->getState('role') === User::ROLE_ADMIN);
    }
}
```

config

```
'components' => array(
        'user' => array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'class' => 'WebUser',
```

But in WebUser there is no role property at all. Any other variations to get it gives error. Question is how to give any data to WebUser from UserIdentity (once on login), but not using additional queries to db (in WebUser).

Answer (score 1):

In your UserIdentity instead of this:

```
$this->role = $oUser->role;
```

Do this:

```
$this->setState('role',$oUser->role);
```

You can also remove the `private $role` from the top.